# Visual Studio Debugging an old version of code- for instantiated classes only

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am debugging a solution in visual studio, and the debugger is not building up to date code for each class. The solution consists of 3 projects:

- Project 1) A windows service- set up for debugging as a console app
- Project 2) An actual console app (which basically functions as a class library and needs to be changed to one at some point)
- Project 3) A unit test project.

Project 1, the windows service, uses quartz scheduler and instantiates classes from project 2, the console app, in some of it's jobs. I am certain the the updated code in project 2 is not being hit because the main job of the scheduler is to send emails, which it still does successfully, and in the code that must be called before any emails are sent I have put:

```
 throw new exception("hello");
```

Visual studio will also not hit any break points I put in the instantiated classes of project 2 when debugging from project 1. Bizarrely however, in a static class full of constants in project 2 if I put:

```
public static readonly string test = textFxn();

private static string testFxn()
{
   throw new exception("hello");
}
```

The debugger will throw the exception, and hit any break points I put in the class.

What have I tried:

- Build solution
- Clean + Rebuild solution
- Delete all bin and obj folders from the solution, then clean + rebuild
- Delete all bin and obj folders from the solution, restart computer, then clean + rebuild
- Delete all bin and obj folders from the solution, delete recycle bin + temp files, then clean + rebuild
- check settings based on similar posts about VS not building up to date code, everything seems to be set to build the new code
- Updating to latest .NET target version

Other details:

- I am debugging under project 1
- Visual studio version is 2017, Windows
- break points / code changes are picked up for project 1, the windows service
- Console.WriteLine() does not appear to be working within project 2, even in places where the code was not updated, I am fairly certain it did before
- I had been working on this solution for months with the same setup and never encountered this issue
- I wrote unit tests for the new code in project 2 which tested the updated code when project 3 was run
- There is a local git folder for the project, but obviously I don't really want to try deleting that

Where on earth (or more specifically, on my computer) is visual studio picking up these old class builds from? I am unable to find anything about anyone having an issue like this so suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up being able to resolve the issue by downgrading my version of Quartz from 3.0.7 to an any arbitrary 2.x version. The behavior was totally bizarre and still unsure of what exactly what Quartz was doing to cause this.